# Show popup on mouseover for each table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I want show a popup when I move the mouse over the text for each row of the table.
The code I use is this:

```js
    $.fn.ready(function() {
        $('#pizzaname').hover(function() {
            $('#popup').show();
        }, function() {
            $('#popup').hide();
        });
    });
```

```html
<%= provide(:title, "Menu") %>

<h1>Le nostre pizze</h1>

<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.rank == "ADMIN" %>
    <%= link_to 'Inserisci una nuova pizza nel Menu', new_product_path %>
<% end %>

  <div class="panel panel-default" %>
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>Lista delle pizze</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table-striped">
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Nome</strong></td>
          <td><strong>Ingredienti</strong></td>
          <td><strong>Prezzo</strong></td>
          <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.rank == "ADMIN" %>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
        <% @products.each do |product| %>
          <tr>
            <td id="pizzaname">
              <%= product.nome_pizza%>
              <div id="popup"
                   style=" height: 50px;
                           width: 200px;
                           display: none;
                           position: absolute;" >
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <%= if File.exist?("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/#{product.id}pizza.jpg")
                          image_tag("#{product.id}pizza.jpg", width: '100%')
                        else
                          image_tag("no-pizza.png", width: '100%')
                        end %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td><em><%= product.ingredienti %></em></td>
            <td><%= number_to_currency(product.prezzo, unit: "€") %></td>
            <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.rank == "ADMIN" %>
                <td><%= link_to 'Mostra', product, class: "btn btn-default" %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Modifica', edit_product_path(product), class: "btn btn-default" %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Cancella', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Sei sicuro?' }, class: "btn btn-default" %></td>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This code show me correctly the popup but for the first row only. If I move the mouse over the name on second, third or any other row the popup don't appear.
Did some test, changed IDs but can't find the error. Any solution?

Comment: ids should be unique in your DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with multiple elements of the same kind (in your case text in multiple rows in the table) always use classes and not IDs in your markup. And then bind the functions accordingly in Javascript.

To help you understand better, IDs are unique identifiers. Like your passport number uniquely identifies you as a person. And only one person in the world has that number. Similarly IDs should be unique for each element. 
Classes on the other hand are used to identify similar entities. For example, a class of Economics students will share some common properties (like the all study Macroeconomics from 9am-10m). Thus in your case, the elements should have the same class name (because the hover effect on each of them) will be a common property.

So your HTML would change like this to use classes instead of IDs

```
.....
<td class="pizzaname">
    <%= product.nome_pizza%>
       <div class="popup" style=" height: 50px;">
.....
```

And your JS would then be

```
  $('.pizzaname').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.popup').show();
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.popup').hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `pizzaname` and `popup` should be classes, and not ids. Change this in HTML:

```
<td class="pizzaname"
<div class="popup"
```

And your jQuery shoul be:

```
$.fn.ready(function() {
    $('.pizzaname').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.popup').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.popup').hide();
    });
});
```

Learn more [here](http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/).